# Wordpress - Select tag gets automatically appended

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-3.9

I wanted to add a drop down list to my wordpress post. So i put this in the text editor

```
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

however once I switch to the visual editor and then back to the text editor, i see this,

```
<select><option value="volvo">Volvo</option></select>
<select><option value="saab">Saab</option></select>
<select><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option></select>
<select><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>
```

why is wordpress automatically appending select tags to each option value?

I am using wordpress 3.9.1 twenty twelve theme

Comment: The editor is notoriously frustrating, I'd actually recommend trying out some of the alternative editor plugins such as [WP Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-edit/) or [WP Super Edit](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-edit/)